# phpmyadmin, 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin, internal-server-error

Since I changed my Wordpress Domain address local address to random.hol.es
and save that.

Just error occurred and I can't do anything.

Please help me.

> --[Thu Aug 04 10:06:30.000889 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3676:tid 428] AH00455: Apache/2.4.10 (Win64) PHP/5.6.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
>   [Thu Aug 04 10:06:30.000889 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3676:tid 428] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Jul 17 2014 12:58:29
>   [Thu Aug 04 10:06:30.000889 2016] [core:notice] [pid 3676:tid 428] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\AutoSet9\Server\bin\httpd.exe -d C:/AutoSet9/server'
>   [Thu Aug 04 10:06:30.004891 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3676:tid 428] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 800
>   [Thu Aug 04 10:06:33.455867 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 800:tid 468] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
>   [Thu Aug 04 10:07:16.406305 2016] [core:alert] [pid 800:tid 932] [client 127.0.0.1:8007] C:/.htaccess: http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin/
>   [Thu Aug 04 10:07:31.378605 2016] [core:alert] [pid 800:tid 928] [client 127.0.0.1:8670] C:/.htaccess: http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin/
>   [Thu Aug 04 10:07:52.853305 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3676:tid 428] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
>   [Thu Aug 04 10:07:54.865613 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 800:tid 468] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
>   [Thu Aug 04 10:07:55.033734 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3676:tid 428] AH00430: Parent: Child process 800 exited successfully.

Comment: Ok, caught : you try to migrate your local server to an online hosting.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you tried to migrate wordpress from your local machine to an online webhosting.

CMS can be tricky to use when doing such task, it's often a good option to get some tutorial, even for advanced user.

Assuming you have a full save of your site, you'd better start from it. Once your local website is retablished, take a look on this [link](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/guide-to-migrating-localhost-wordpress-to-live-site/) you will learn how to use Duplicator, an easy tool to migrate your website.

if you don't have any save of your site, please tell us where you did change the value from local to hol.es, so we can guide you on a manual repair.